# Editing an attribute of an entity using a different attribute of the same entity as the key

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity called Student.
And the entity has attributes StudentName and Register Number.
The attribute StudentName has multiple unsorted values set by the user.
How do I sort the values of StudentName? And how to I programmatically set values to respective instances of the attribute RegisterNumber?

Basically, how do I set the value of RegisterNumber based on the set value of StudentName?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean with "entry"? What do you mean by assigning? setting the property yourself after you initialised the class, or have it happen automatically?
If you want it to happen automatically, you might be able to do it with lazy loading

Comment: By entry, I mean an instance of the entity (class). I set the value for Name myself (or actually the user does it), and sort the number of students alphabetically, then I want to have a RegisterNumber be assigned automatically based on the position (index) of the Name.

Sorry, I am actually very new to programming, and Swift is the first language I am learning. So, I am not very good at elaborating.

Comment: It may help to think about this... If you were trying to answer the question, what information would you need to do that properly. Also, rather than placing the additional information in comments, please edit you question and add the information in the original question text. This makes it easier for us to follow you question.

Comment: You will have to do this 'manually' I think. After you sorted your list (I'm assuming it's an array), you can loop through the list using `for (index, object) in enumerate(list) { object.registerNumber = yourValueBasedOnIndex }`

Comment: To sort the list, take a look at the `.sort()` function. A quick google search on 'swift sort array' will provide you an answer